# Why should a DG-module homomorphism also be a chain map?

Tags: proof-verification, homological-algebra

According to every definition in the literature, (1) a homomorphism of DG-modules must be a chain map [[Stacks Project]](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09JH).  This is perfectly reasonable at first glance, especially if you want to use the forgetful functor to chain complexes.

It also seems reasonable, or so I thought, that (2) a DG-algebra $A$ is a right (and left) DG-module over itself.  In particular, for every $a\in A$ it seems reasonable that $\mu_{a}: A\to A$, $\mu_{a}(b) = a * b$ should be a right DG-module homomophism.

Claim: Properties (1) and (2) are incompatible.

Proof by example.  Consider a DG-algebra $A$ which is an object in the image in the category of DG-algebras of the monoidal Dold-Kan correspondence [[nLab]](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+Dold-Kan+correspondence).  Here is the most concrete nontrivial example:

Let $A_{0}, A_{1}$ be subrings of a commutative ring $A_{01}$.  Let $A^{0} = A_{0} \oplus A_{1}$, and $A^{1} = A_{01}$, and $A = A^{0} \oplus A^{1}$.  Define $d(a_{0},a_{1},a_{01}) = (0, 0, a_{1} - a_{0})$, and the DG-algebra multiplication to be:

$$
a * b = (a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{01}) * (b_{0}, b_{1}, b_{01}) = (a_{0} b_{0}, a_{1} b_{1}, a_{0} b_{01} + a_{01} b_{1})
$$

Where the products $a_{*}b_{*}$ happen inside $A_{01}$.

Claim: $A$ is a DG-algebra, but $\mu_{a}$ is not a chain map.

Proof: For simplicity choose $|a| = 0$, so $a = (a_{0}, a_{1}, 0)$.  Then

$$
d(\mu_{a}(b)) = d(a * b) = d(a_{0} b_{0}, a_{1} b_{1}, a_{0} b_{01}) = (0, 0, a_{1} b_{1} - a_{0} b_{0})
$$
but
$$
\mu_{a}(d(b)) = \mu_{a}(0, 0, b_{1} - b_{0}) = (0, 0, a_{0}(b_{1} - b_{0}) )
$$

This is rarely a chain map.  The failure of it to be a chain map is measured by $da$:

$$
d(\mu_{a}(b)) - \mu_{a}(d(b)) = (0, 0, (a_{1} - a_{0}) b_{1})
$$

Am I crazy here?  Because of the application I need them for, I would much rather have (2) be true and dispose of property (1) from the definition of a DG-module homomorphism.

Comment: Suppose that $b\mapsto ab$ is a DG-module morphism. Then in particular $d(ab) =ad b$ for any $b$, and setting $b=1$ gives $da=0$ since $d1=0$.  Conversely, $da=0$ implies $b\mapsto ab$ is a DG-module morphism. (You seem to have forgotten DG-morphisms should commute with the differential. In particular, left multiplication is always right linear, and graded if the element is homogeneous. It commutes with the differential *precisely* when this homogeneous element is a cycle.)

Comment: Well, I haven't forgotten it, in fact it's the title and first sentence of my question.  What I'm trying to understand is what I lose by considering, say, the category of graded A-modules with a degree 1 differential, with A-linear graded homomorphisms (i.e., DG-modules minus commuting with the differential).  This is more a question about nomenclature and the fact that I'd like A to be an object in its own category of modules.  If this simply isn't ever considered in the literature, that's fine, I'll just revise my terminology.

Comment: The problem is those morphisms won't give you homological data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In particular, for every $a \in A$ it seems reasonable that $\mu_a : A \to A, \mu_a(b) = ab$ should be a right DG-module homomophism.

This is incorrect. The correct claim is that if $a$ is a $0$-cycle then $\mu_a$ is a dg module homomorphism. Explicitly, we have

$$d(ab) = d(a) b + (-1)^{|a|} a \, d(b)$$

and so if $|a| = da = 0$ then $d(ab) = a \, d(b)$, making multiplication by $a$ a chain map.

More generally, multiplication defines a morphism

$$A \to [A, A]$$

of chain complexes, where $[A, A]$ is the internal hom of chain complexes. Homomorphisms are given by $0$-cycles in the internal hom, and more generally morphisms of degree $n$ are given by $n$-cycles.

Comment: I'm still looking for a category where $A$ is a (blank)-module over itself.  Multiplication is still graded and $A$-linear, so it's like a twisted or pseudo homomorphism.  Would the idea of having a "pseudo" morphism of chain complexes which isn't a chain map be so confusing to the reader that I should just abandon this pursuit?

Comment: @S K: $A$ is in fact a dg module over itself. This doesn't mean that every element of $A$ gives a dg module homomorphism; to give a dg module structure on a chain complex $V$ is the same as giving a morphism $A \to [V, V]$ of dg algebras, where $[-, -]$ again denotes the internal hom.